# Xcode 4.6 failed with exit code 255

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, xcode4.6, xcode5

I am developing iOS app,

I have upgraded my Mac os from Lion to Mountain Lion today, and i was using `Xcode 4.6(iOS 5)` in lion.

but now in mountain Lion, i have installed `Xcode 5 DP`,

Now when i try to run my app in `Xocde 4.6` it shows me error like this,

```
ibtoold[2032:707] [MT] DVTAssertions: ASSERTION FAILURE in /SourceCache/IDEInterfaceBuilder/IDEInterfaceBuilder-3084/Framework/Document/IBObjectContainer.m:336Details:  ID is too lowObject:   <IBObjectContainer: 0x401134c20>Method:   -setMaxID:Thread:   <NSThread: 0x40030a260>{name = (null), num = 1}Hints: NoneBacktrace:  0  0x0000000101c84ec3 -[DVTAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:fileName:lineNumber:messageFormat:arguments:] (in DVTFoundatio  1  0x0000000101c84cf4 _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundatio  2  0x000000010130ffda -[IBObjectContainer setMaxID:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKi  3  0x0000000101298f31 -[IBDocument unarchiveDocument:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKi  4  0x000000010142af22 -[IBDocumentUnarchiver recurseWithElement:kind:invokingBlock:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKi  5  0x000000010142b0f6 -[IBDocumentUnarchiver unarchiveDocument:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKi  6  0x0000000101293cfb __47-[IBDocument readFromFileWrapper:ofType:error:]_block_invoke (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKi  7  0x00000001012b6ea4 -[IBDocument runBlockInNewArbitrationStackEntryWithBehavior:block:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKi  8  0x0000000101293b14 -[IBDocument readFromFileWrapper:ofType:error:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKi  9  0x0000000105232019 (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegratio 10  0x00000001052da154 (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration 11  0x0000000105232094 (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration 12  0x00007fff97d2e527 -[NSDocument readFromURL:ofType:error:] (in AppKit 13  0x000000010128e2d1 __39-[IBDocument readFromURL:ofType:error:]_block_invoke (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit 14  0x00000001012b0f9a -[IBDocument invokeWithUndoSuppressed:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit 15  0x000000010128e08d -[IBDocument readFromURL:ofType:error:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit 16  0x00000001011ab170 (in ibtoold 17  0x00000001011a750f (in ibtoold 18  0x00000001011a6792 (in ibtoold 19  0x00000001011a6640 (in ibtoold 20  0x00000001011b2f5d (in ibtoold 21  0x00000001011a61a2 (in ibtoold 22  0x00000001011aa2ad (in ibtoold 23  0x00000001011a4f74 (in ibtoold 24  0x000000000000000Command
```

**/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool failed with exit code 255**

what should i do now ?

***Thanks in advance.***

Comment: I'd suggest you upgrade XCode to 4.6.3(latest). It is more stable than 4.6

Comment: after downloading 4.6.3, is it neccessary to uninstall xcode 4.6 ?

Comment: Have you tried `Product > Clean`?

Comment: It will automatically be overwritten.  Did you by any chance open your project with Xcode 5?

Comment: yes i have tried `Product > Clean` also reinstall of Xcode 4.6 but facing the same problem.

Comment: I have tried with xcode 5, it is working but it crashes sometimes without any reason... so i want back to come back to xcode 4.6

Comment: I heard that XCode 5 change some things on the source (xib I think). That could be the problem

Comment: You should limit questions about non-released Xcode's to Apple's forum site.

Comment: @Amar please mark your comment as answer, i wil accept that. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you upgrade XCode to 4.6.3(latest). It is more stable than 4.6

Comment: In my case this was happening with Jenkins with an unmodified Xib file. Just relaunching the job fixed this...